# What is the best way to create a reusable top menu with a dropdown list

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a ViewController (TopMenuViewController) in my storyboard that has my app logo and a button that shows a dropdown list when I click on it, this dropdown list has button (logout, about, settings ....). 
All the screens in my application has this top menu, so I decided to create a ViewController for this top menu and add a container in all the other screens that embed the TopMenuViewController.

My Top menu view controller has a height 53 and when the dropdown list is shown the height will be 227

[image]

I embed this Top menu view controller into all my viewcontrollers, for example my Main Screen View Controller:

[image]

I added the following constraints to this container: 
[image]

Now, the issue is I'm not be able to click on any button on this dropdown list because the constraint height is 53, and if I change it to 227, I will not be able to click on the buttons that are under this dropdown list.

What is the best way to create a reusable top menu with a dropdown list.

Comment: You need to change the constraint programatically when you want to display the menu.  You can create an `IBOutlet` to the constraint from IB just like any other item, then you can animate a change to it when required

Comment: @Paulw11 I have tried to that in the Top Menu View Controller but the changes are not reflect to the container.

Comment: If you change the height to 227 in IB does the screen look how you want to it (I understand that that the content view will be obscured)? If so then either you aren't changing the right constraint at run time or you didn't call `setNeedsLayout` after changing the constraint

Comment: I'm not calling SetNeedsLayout, where should I call it? the things that is conflicting me is the idea of changing the container view according to its content. @Paulw11

Comment: After you change a constraint you need to call `setNeedsLayout` - You haven't shown your code, but normally your menu controller would be your root view controller and it would have a container view - as you move through your app you change the content of this container view.  When you need to display the menu you simply change the menu height constraint in the root view and call `setNeedsLayout` (preferably in an animation block) to hide it, do the same thing with the original constraint value

Comment: Thanks for you response @Paulw11, but in my app I have the top menu in a view controller and in all the other views have a container that embed the top menu view controller. So, how to allow these containers to change their height, and how to listen to the top menu height changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71410/discussion-between-paulw11-and-mouhamad-kawas).